# Rails helper methods: @ vs normal variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Michael Hartl's rails tutorial we have a `current_user` method defined as such:

```
  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

At first I assumed `@current_user` was needed as opposed to some other local variable like `the_current_user` (assuming you can't use `current_user` since that's the name of the method.

When using helper methods that return something, do we need an `@` variable or can we just use any variable type? (I saw other helper_methods use normal `variable_names`). (Im assuming `@current_user` was just convenient)

Comment: `@current_user` is not a local variable. `@current_user` is not abnormal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` makes variables available throughout the class.

If was just `current_user` instead of `@current_user` it would only be accessible inside of that specific method.

You can use `current_user` as a variable name inside of a method named `current_user`

---

you don't need to use `@` before an instance variable to return a value.

```
def some_method
  user = "Jimmy"
  user
end

> puts some_method
"Jimmy"
```

Comment: I meant from what was being returned. like if we returned a non `@` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a common Ruby idiom, up close:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: something)
end
```

You can call `current_user` as often as you like, now, because it will only spend time hitting the database the first time you call it. On subsequent calls, `@current_user` has a value, so the `||=` evaluates trivially as `@current_user = @current_user`.

The effect lasts as long as the `@` instance exists. If it's a controller, it will last for the current action, and then disappear. This means a new action with a different user will not trip over the previous value of `@current_user`.

Because `def current_user` occupies a namespace different from `@current_user`, the Ruby idiom is to name the "memento pattern" variable the same as the method it optimizes.

Your example makes the memento pattern a little confusing, because there are two ways to generate a current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can return normal variable in helper methods.

`@` is just a syntax used to define an instance variable.

`@current_user` is just a convention, you can use any name like `@whatever_user`

Answer (score 1):

For example, if we are using `current_user` instead of `@current_user` then you will not be able to access `current_user` from any of your views.

For example, if you want to show the name of the user if the user is signed in:

```
<%= @current_user.name if @current_user %>
```

It is possible only because we have used the instance variable.

Following will help you in knowing more about instance variable:

https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/instancevars.html
http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/instance_variables.html

To know about all the types of variables available in Ruby:
https://www.studytonight.com/ruby/types-of-variables-in-ruby

### Side Note

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
```

This pattern is called memoization. It is a very common pattern in Ruby/Rails. You can read more about it here:

https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/

Comment: Ah, I forgot about views. But "normal" non-instance variables can still be accessed in other controllers for example correct? Just not in a view.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `Other` controller.  Local(normal) variables can be used in a controller. But not across the methods e.g. you can't use the variable defined in `create` method in your `update` method. For that, you need instance variable.